# How to avoid bitmap out of memory when working on very large image for ie: 10.000.000 pixel and above

Tags: c#, bitmap, system.drawing

Currently i'm working on a system that load a very large image, with minimum width x heigh >= 10.000.000 pixel.

But the ratio of the user's upload image usually do not match our requirement ratio so i have to crop it to proper ratio, but when using System.Drawing bitmap to crop it, i always got SytemOutOfMemory exception.

I have try Bitmap.Clone and Graphic.DrawImage with correct RectangleF but no luck.

Is there anyways to do this without getting the outofmemory exception or are there any alternatives to System.Drawing library to get this task done easily ?

My code to load the image from user upload file:

```
    var fileBinary = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(fileBinary, 0, fileBinary.Length);
    stream.Position = 0;
    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    using (Image image = Image.FromStream(stream, false, false))
    {
        //validation and check ratio
        CropImage(image, PORTRAIT_RATIO, fileExtension);
     }
```

And the CropImage function:

```
//Crop Image from center with predefine ratio
    private byte[] CropImage(Image sourceImg, float ratio, string fileExtension)
        var height = sourceImg.Height;
        var width = sourceImg.Width;

        var isPortrait = width < height;
        RectangleF croppingRec = new RectangleF();

        float positionX = 0;
        float positionY = 0;
        float cropHeight = (float)height;
        float cropWidth = cropHeight * PORTRAIT_RATIO;
        positionY = 0;
        positionX = (width - cropWidth) / 2;

        if (cropWidth > width)
        {
            cropWidth = width;
            cropHeight = cropWidth * (1 / PORTRAIT_RATIO);
            positionX = 0;
            positionY = ((height - cropHeight) / 2);

        }

        croppingRec.Width = cropWidth;
        croppingRec.Height = cropHeight;
        croppingRec.X = positionX;
        croppingRec.Y = positionY;

        Bitmap bmpImage = sourceImg as Bitmap;
        Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(croppingRec, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
        bmpCrop.Save("D:/test" + fileExtension, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();

        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmpCrop, typeof(byte[]));
    }

}
```

Comment: check out http://imageresizing.net/

Comment: did you try to compile as `64bit` app with special flag that removes memory restrictions from the clr (apart of max 2GB for single List<T> collection) ?

Comment: 10 million pixels is not normally a problem,  Half a billion is the theoretical maximum but in a 32-bit process you tend to fall over well before that.  Usually around 25 million if your program has been running for a while.  Most likely bug in your code is forgetting to call Dispose(), it is a rock-hard requirement when you use the Bitmap class and way too many programmers forget about it.  Nobody can see your bug when you don't post your code.

Comment: Tks jle, Tigran and Hans for respond to my answer.

Comment: Since you mention uploads, it might be worth drawing your attention to the warning on the [System.Drawing namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or *ASP.NET service*."

Comment: Kinda obvious from the code, *bmpCrop* will never be disposed.  You must do so after you converted it to byte[].

Comment: Do the clients upload via a web page?

Comment: Yes, the clients upload the picture via ajax and we have to crop the img to correct ratio for beautiful display on web pages.

Comment: Where exactly does it throw the exception?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the bitmap to a byte array. Try something like this (looks hackie but i don't know another way):

```
int pixelSize = 3;
int bytesCount = imgHeight * imgWidth * pixelSize;
byte[] byteArray= new byte[bytesCount];

BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, byteArray, 0, bytesCount);
```

Each pixel in this array is represented by 3 bytes (this depends on the bitmap type). So you know that lenght of a bitmap line is 3 * imgWidth. Using this you could simply navigate in the byte array and copy just what you need into a new array.

You would then create a new bitmap with the desired final size, get the bitmap data and Marshal.Copy the new array into that:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
BitmapData newBitmapData = b.LockBits(BoundsRect,
                                ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                newBitmap.PixelFormat);
Marshal.Copy(newByteArray, 0, newBitmapData.Scan0, newBytesCount);
```

Unlock the bitmaps at the end:

```
newBitmap.UnlockBits(newBitmapData );
bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [graphicsmagick.net](https://graphicsmagick.codeplex.com/) library, then use the Crop method on MagickImage. It should still work well under asp.net, and handles huge image files using disk for scratch.