# Is there a way to create a bitmap in fragments in C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm trying to create an enormous bitmap 52000x29250 `PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb` which is impossible the normal way because it will take ~ 24.3GB of RAM. So can I somehow create a bitmap in fragments and create one huge bitmap from those fragments?

Comment: see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545200/c-sharp-how-to-avoid-bitmap-out-of-memory-when-working-on-very-large-image-for-i

Comment: since you want to merge these bitmaps at the end you should look for way to not load that into memory and work only with filestream or something like that.

Comment: See webpage : https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that you never need to load the Bitmap into memory. Just treat it as a file stream of bytes. Construct a reader/writer class for handling the actual bitmap binary format, and use that reader/writer class for addressing the bitmap data.

This allows you to construct and process a bitmap of any scale in a highly memory efficient way. You can tune up and tune down the performance simply by increasing the stream cache.

The key to large scale bitmap processing is to handle it just like you would a database; no programmer ever reads an entire database into memory; so you dont need to do it for bitmaps.

The format of a PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb Bitmap is well documented and if you google around you might find an existing reader/writer class for them.

Comment: _The format of a Bitmap is well documented_ Do you mean Bitmap or BMP?

Comment: PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb is a well documented format. Updated the answer for clarity.

Comment: Well, yes, but it is not a file format. Some compression schemes need to acces the whole image to do their stats. I wonder how that translates into stream IO; just curious..

Comment: Ah, well the file format may be different - for instance the OP might be using a DirectX format such as DDS, but I'm guessing they are using BMP or JPG. The reader/writer class needs to know about the physical file format, but any algorithm applied to the bitmap data extracted from the stream is based on its PixelFormat.